# How to replace two elements in a list if both are the same (Python)

Tags: python, list, replace

I want to replace elements in a list if they coincide in the same list untill there is only an 1 in the list. If I have [1,0,1,0,1], the list becomes [0,0,1,0,0] or something like that, only with an 1... but it doesnt replace elements and it prints the same list...

```
 import random 

p = float(input("Introduzca probabilidad de transmisión: "))
q = 1 - p
usuarios = ['Usuario1','Usuario2', 'Usuario3', 'Usuario 4', 'Usuario5']
transmisiones = []

for i in usuarios:
    if random.random() < p:
        transmisiones.append(1)
    else:
        transmisiones.append(0)

    print(transmisiones)

    for elemento in transmisiones:
        if elemento == 1 and transmisiones[0:5] == 1:
            transmisiones[elemento] = 0


    print(transmisiones)




    output:

    Introduzca probabilidad de transmisión: 0.6
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more details in your question to let others understand what are you trying to do and where is the problem?

Comment: You've got `transmisiones[0:5] == 1` but `transmisiones[0:5]` is a list and a list will never be the same as the integer value `1`. Did you mean to check all or any element(s) of the list?

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeeeees, checking all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should write like this

```
idx= -1
for i in range(len(transmisiones)):
        if transmisiones[i] == 1:
            idx = i
        transmisiones[i] = 0

transmisiones[idx] = 1
```

the `idx` always keep the last index where the value is equal to 1

if you want all the indices to be saved append them in the a list

Comment: @JuanAntonioRamírezPeña welcome,kindly mark the question as answered